# XMLPath Query with "OR" Operator

Tags: xpath

I got an `.xml` file which has the following entries:

```
<country>
<province id="prov-cid-cia-Greece-3" country="GR">
    <name>Attiki</name>
    <area>3808</area>
    <population>3522769</population>
    <city id="cty-Greece-Athens" is_country_cap="yes" country="GR" province="prov-cid-cia-Greece-3">
        <name>Athens</name>
        <longitude>23.7167</longitude>
        <latitude>37.9667</latitude>
        <population year="81">885737</population>
        <located_at watertype="sea" sea="sea-Mittelmeer"/>
     </city>
</province>
</country>
```

However, there are also nodes which are called `city` without the `province` as a parent:

```
<country>
    <city id="stadt-Shkoder-AL-AL" country="AL">
        <name>Shkoder</name>
        <longitude>19.2</longitude>
        <latitude>42.2</latitude>
        <population year="87">62000</population>
        <located_at watertype="lake" lake="lake-Skutarisee"/>
    </city>
</country>
```

Without further explanation, I want to select all nodes `city`, however, in my current query it selects only `cities` without `province` as a parent

```
query = f"//country/city[@is_country_cap = \"yes\" and ./located_at[@watertype]]/name/text()"
```

How could I include the `/province/country` in my query? I have tried:

```
query = f"//country/(city | ./province/city)[@is_country_cap = \"yes\" and ./located_at[@watertype]]/name/text()"
```

without any success, I get an Error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can match for all `<city>` elements that have a parent of `<country>` or `<province>`. Then, in a second predicate, add your other requirements like this:

```
//city[parent::country or parent::province][@is_country_cap = 'yes' and located_at[@watertype]]/name
```

Or, approaching your language

```
query = f"//city[parent::country or parent::province][@is_country_cap = \"yes\" and located_at[@watertype]]/name/text()"
```

Maybe this is of some help to you.
Your mistake has been using the `|` operator instead of the keyword `or`. In XPath, the `|` operator means "merge nodesets" and not a logical "OR" like in C.

Comment: Your solution works, ty! However, I am using Python and the library `lxlml.etree`. `or` is not supported there apparently, and only `|` works. But I forgot to mention that in the post regardless

Comment: Actually, `//city[parent::country | parent::province]` is fine in XPath 1.0. However, `/country/(province | .)/city` requires XPath 2.0 -- 1.0 doesn't allow a parenthesized expression to be used on the RHS of "/" in this way.

Comment: Thank you for your expertise. However, the XPath version hasn't been specified in the question, so IDK and assumed version 1.0.